# Animation jQuery UI draggable element back to starting position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an element, let's say a div, that I want to be able to drag and drop into another div. If the element isn't dragged into the other div I would like it to animate back to it's initial position. The draggable divs are relatively positioned. So, my question is what's the best approach? Is there a method in jQuery UI which will allow it to animate back? Or am I going to have to write it? If I do, here's my strategy:

1. get coordinates of the draggable div on start of drag using `$('#draggableElement').css('left')`, and `$('#draggableElement').css('top')`
2. On drag complete use the jQuery .animate to put it back in place.

Is that strategy correct? Or is there something more efficient I could be doing?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#revert

Comment: You could try using webkit for such stuff, but the comment above answers ur question!

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I could have sworn that wasn't there last week when I checked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#revert)

and maybe the helper of a jquery [ui draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) options -> helper.

I think this should help you. If not, please specify your question.

Comment: The helper is the object, that is dragged. That means you could modify the html element, that follows the mouse. Have a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback for the different helper styles.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `revert: 'invalid'`

example:

```
$( "#draggablediv" ).draggable({helper : "clone", revert: "invalid" });
```

the `helper:clone` makes a clone when you try to drag it, when you dont drop it in the area the `revert: "invalid"` returns the clone to his start position.

**If you want the dragable to return to his position use `revert: "true"`**

Please see http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert